# Examples of time series models on other than economic data

Tags: time-series, references, arima, vector-autoregression

All our text book examples are based on macro economic problems, but there must be many applications of time series models on other data, such as for example windspeed, average heartbeat, gas turbine efficiency, factory output, etc.

Do you know on the web textbook examples about these non economic applications of Arima and Var models?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some papers on the subject: http://vbn.aau.dk/files/18915270/Corrected_Dec072009_ARIMA_Based_Time_Series_Model_of_Stochastic_Wind_Power_Generation.pdf
http://www.academia.edu/1258592/Short_Term_Wind_Speed_Forecasting_Using_Time_Series_Models

Just about any textbook on weather forecasting also covers this material, however as you'll see it does require background knowledge of physics / atmospheric sciences to properly understand *why* these things are modelled this way. Economic applications are far more accessible, hence the reason they're included in general purpose time series textbooks.

Comment: Thx, I also already found these papers about wind forecasting. I don't really get how simple wind or temperature or other engineering models can require more background knowledge as inflation, exchange rates, quantitative easing etc? They are the most difficult subjects of them all!

Comment: Modelling economic time-series ain't as easy as you may think; have you read any serious graduate macro or econometric textbooks or papers from top journs? The claim that "economic applications are far more accessible, hence the reason they're included in general purpose time series textbooks" is very much contestable.

Comment: Accessible =/= easy. Unlike engineering models, you can find accessible explanations of economic models in most reputable newspapers and magazines (e.g."The Economist") because of the inherent debate that emerges from evaluating a proposal/policy. The same can't really be said of engineering models. "Here's what the weather forecast is, case closed."

Comment: Ah! _That_ kind of economics. If anything, I hear something similar to "here's what the weather forecast is, case closed" when I watch the weather news on TV. One could argue that one of the challenges for economists is to actually provide accessible explanations of econom(etr)ic models since they can be quite difficult to understand & interpret. Communicating the results of, say, a large scale structural model to a politician-let alone the general public-is not easy; no matter how easy reading The Economist might seem. Thankfully we have impulse response functions, and, well, so do engineers!

Comment: True, but it does not help matters at all that every pundit thinks himself capable of evaluating economic policy and yet mysteriously completely incapable of contesting the weather forecast. Better PR from the economist side would also help. You can't have Alan Greenspan publicly say that "we can't forecast all that well" and he mistakenly thought banks would be better stewards of their own capital and then expect the public to think that the economist profession requires expertise and should be respected.

Comment: You state the crux of the problem: every pundit thinks himself capable of evaluating economic policy! The _better PR_ you refer to is the _challenge_ that I mentioned. Lastly, while I'd love to debate, I don't think the matter warrants any further discussion - better to address what's at the heart of the OP's question.